# Having expanded color scheme menu by default in MacVim and gVim

Tags: vim

I don't know exactly when, but at some point instead of having the color schemes expanded by default under `edit->color scheme`, gVim and MacVim started having an `edit->Show Color Schemes in Menu` menu item instead which, once selected, expands into what was previously the `edit->color scheme` menu item containing all the color schemes.

I can't seem to find any setting to have the menu item be in its expanded form by default. Is this perhaps a hardwired behaviour that has to be configured when building gVim/MacVim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Lazy GUI menu expansion is on by default. To switch it off you must create a special variable before `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` was sourced (top of vimrc could probably do):

```
let g:do_no_lazyload_menus = 1
```

See also `:h no_buffers_menu`.

And let me repeat again: the variable must be created before `menu.vim` was sourced (hence before `filetype on`). So always refer to `:scriptnames` output and do extra checks. No one can imagine how "smart" package maintainers cripple Vim config.

Comment: That did it. This one was a little tricky to google for, so thank you!